# Remove specific pattern with sed

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sed, regular-expression

I have a variable which contains a JSON format like this:

```
$variable = "{"ids":953,"hostName":"CI-KR81-02","pcModel",..,}"
```

I want to remove the ids part so the file looks like that:

```
$variable = {"hostName":"CI-KR81-02","pcModel",..}
```

I already tried `'sed 's/^.*\(hostName\)/\1/' <<< "$value"`

But it removes also the "{" part

and the output looks like this

```
hostName":"CI-KR81-02","pcModel",..}
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

OK I found how to do it.
I needed to exclude { with [{]

```
sed -e 's/\([{]\).*\("hostName\)/\1\2/'
```